# Php Server Side Security

Tags: php, security

I try to code new application. User's uploading their php script and all scripts stored in 1 folder like that;

- Some folder
- Another System Folder
- Projects Folder

  - project 1

    - index.php
  - project 2

    - index.php
  - project 3

    - index.php
- index.php

But it's not secure. For example;

```php
// in project1->index.php
<?php
include '../project2/indexphp'
```

İt's problem. I want to fix it how can I do with server side? Can ı create spesific user for each project?

Comment: You can, but if you're concerned about malicious users, letting them upload executable code is not a good idea at all, even if they're in separate users.

Comment: @ceejayoz so wat should I do? I can't block include because it's important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ITK module in Apache to assign a user to a DocumentRoot.The trick is configure de *home* to match to DocumentRoot

1. Create user: `adduser -m -d /home/app newuser`
2. Set `newuser` password: `passwd newuser`
3. Install MPM ITK ([CentosInstallation](https://blog.daneted.com/2016/03/mpm-itk-en-apache-24-centos-7-asignar.html))
4. Configure virtualhost (It's a basic configuration)

> ```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
>     ServerName app.example.com
>     DocumentRoot /home/app
>     ErrorLog /var/log/www/app.error.log
>     CustomLog /var/log/www/app.requests.log combined
>     <IfModule mpm_itk_module>
>         AssignUserId newuser newuser
>     </IfModule>
>     <Directory /home/app>
>         Require all granted
>         AllowOverride all
>     </Directory>
> </VirtualHost>
> ```

5. Restart Apache
6. Use the new user to upload the files via sFTP to FTP if you have the FTP service installed.

**Sometimes it's necessary allows `newuser` write on the session directory**